# Jenkins Email Notification Variables

Tags: email, jenkins, jelly

I tried to trigger an email after build and I found hard to display the build details via my jelly script. I am getting error as "Could not parse jelly script:null"

I am getting these issue when I customize this html [ 
${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"} ] template and run that via server (jenkins_home/email-templates/*.jelly ).

And I want to get Build Duration, Build Timestamp - Could you let me know how can I achieve this ?

In addition , is there any variable defined to get Build status, build artifacts, junit test results ? e.g Like as we use JOB_NAME for getting the project name.

Thanks
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are using the [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin for sending mails generated from a jelly script (though you didn't specifically name it).

The error indicates that you probably have a null pointer exception somewhere in your script. A good way to debug jelly scripts is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117625/3303940) so answer - basically you can use the Jenkins script console to test your template after a modification, without having to run a new build.

To get an idea about how to get specific information, you could look into the default templates (which you probably tried to customize), as well as the [jenkins documentation](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/), to see what properties/functions an object has.

The examples you mentioned, like the build duration and timestamp should already appear in the [default html template](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/html.jelly) delivered with the plugin, see:

```
<TR><TD>Date of build:</TD><TD>${it.timestampString}</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Build duration:</TD><TD>${build.durationString}</TD></TR>
```